# De Rham Cohomology of $M \times \mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a closed (compact, without boundary) $m$-dimensional manifold. I want to prove that $H^{k+1}(M \times \mathbb{S}^1) = H^k(M) \oplus H^{k+1}(M)$. ($H^k$ is the $k$-th De Rham cohomology group.)

I tried with the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, in two ways. First, I considered the decomposition $M \times \mathbb{S}^1 = (M \times e^{i(0, 3/2 \pi)}) \cup (M \times e^{i(\pi, 5/2 \pi)})$, but apparently it does not work. I tried also the following. Let $U, W \subset M$ diffeomorphic to an $m$-dimensional open ball, and let $\overline W \subset U$. Then the decomposition for the manifold would be

$$
M \times \mathbb{S}^1 = (U \times \mathbb{S}^1) \cup ((M \setminus \overline W) \times \mathbb{S}^1)
$$
The argument would the use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence taking into account the fact that introducing a hole should ''reduce dimensions'' and hence help with induction.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why does it "apparently not work"?

Comment: Are you obliged to solve the exercise using the MV sequence? If not, Kunneth formula should help you finish in a couple of lines.

Comment: This problem only makes sense if he is not able to use he Künneth formula, of course...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: with the first decomposition, I get $\sum_{i = 0}^m (-1)^i \text{dim}(H^i(M \times \mathbb{S}^1)) = 0$, and I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: @Second, there is much more information available from the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence in the first approach. You can explicitly find every third map in the sequence (it is not hard to describe the maps $H^i(U) \oplus H^i(V) \to H^i(U\cap V)$). This is equivalent to decomposing the long exact sequence into many short exact sequences, which should be enough to finish the task.

Comment: @Dmitry, so the point would be to prove that the image of the map $H^i(U) \oplus H^i(V) \to H^i(U \cap V)$, which is to say, up to homotopy, the image of $H^i(M) \oplus H^i(M) \to H^i(M) \oplus H^i(M)$ is isomorphic to $H^i(M)$.

Comment: @Second, yes, something like this. This map is a sum of $H^i(U) \to H^i(U\cap V)$ and $H^i(V) \to H^i(U\cap V)$. As $U\cap V$ is a disjoint union, we may look at maps not to $H^i(U \cap V)$, but to the $i$-th cohomology of one of components, name it $W$ (the other one works similarly). Now this is easy: map $H^i(U) \to H^i(W)$ is induced by the $M \times [0, 1/2] \hookrightarrow M \times [0, 1]$. It only remains to prove this mapping is identity on cohomology (both sides are isomorphic to $H^i(M)$, but the mapping could be nontrivial) and patch a bit up to get the description of a map.