# A special case of Künneth formula

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was studying de Rham cohomology and came upon an exercice with which I'm struggling.

You take a connected differential (smooth) manifold $M$ and set $I=\mathbb{S}^1 -\{(0,1)\}$, $J=\mathbb{S}^1 -\{(0,-1)\}$ and $U=I\times M$, $V=J\times M$.

By computing the kernel of the Mayer-Vietoris morphism
$H^k(U)\times H^k(V)\rightarrow H^k(U\cap V)$, it asks us to prove:
$$H^k(\mathbb{S}^1 \times M)\simeq H^k(M)\oplus H^{k-1}(M)$$
I know this is a special case of the Künneth formula, but the general case is very difficult.

If you have an idea, I would gladly appreciate.

**Edit**
So I think I got it.

So I need to settle some more notations:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{S}^1 &=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|\ |z|=1\}\\
I &=\{e^{i\theta}|\ \theta\neq\frac{\pi}{2}\ \mbox{mod}\ 2\pi\}\\
J &=\{e^{i\theta}|\ \theta\neq -\frac{\pi}{2}\ \mbox{mod}\ 2\pi\}\\
A &=\{e^{i\theta}|\ \frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{3\pi}{2}\}\\
B &=\{e^{i\theta}|\ -\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}\}\\
U &=I\times M\\
V &=J\times M
\end{align}
$$

And now you have this big diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 A\times M & & & & U & \xrightarrow{\pi_N} & M\\
           & \searrow{u_A} & & \underline{i}\nearrow & & & \\
           & & U\cap V & & & & \\
           & \nearrow{u_B} & & \underline{j}\searrow & & & \\
 B\times M & & & & U & \xrightarrow{\pi_S} & M\\
\end{array}
$$
where $u_A$ and $u_B$ are just canonical inclusions.
It goes contravariantly to a diagram of cohomology groups:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 H^(A\times M) & & & & H^k(U) & \xleftarrow{\pi_N ^*} & H^k(M)\\
           & \nwarrow{u_A ^*} & & \underline{i^*}\swarrow & & & \\
           & & H^k(U\cap V) & & & & \\
           & \swarrow{u_B ^*} & & \underline{j^*}\nwarrow & & & \\
 H^k(B\times M) & & & & H^k(U) & \xleftarrow{\pi_S ^*} & H^(M)\\
\end{array}
$$

Now we can look at $M$ as a deform retract of $U,V$
so the "retractions" $\pi_N,\pi_S$
induce isomorphisms $\pi_N^* ,\pi_S ^*$
(This is the thing that I'm hesitant about).

So now I just define the sum function of $\pi_N ^*$ and $\pi_S^*$:
$$\begin{align}
\pi : H^k(M) &\longrightarrow H^k(U)\oplus H^k(V)\\
      \omega &\longmapsto (\pi_N ^*\omega , \pi_S^* \omega)
\end{align}
$$

And I want to show that it's an isomorphism on the kernel of the Mayer Vietoris map
$\underline{i^*}-\underline{j^*}: H^k(U)\oplus H^k(V)\rightarrow H^k (U\cap V)$

Since $\pi_N \circ \underline{i} =\pi_S \circ \underline{j} = \mbox{pr}$
we clearly get $\mbox{Im}(\pi)\subseteq \mbox{Ker}(\underline{i^*}-\underline{j^*})$

The other inclusion: we take $(\epsilon_1 , \epsilon_2)\in\mbox{Ker}(\underline{i^*}-\underline{j^*})$.
But $\pi_N ^*,\pi_S^*$ are isomorphisms so we have $(\epsilon_1 , \epsilon_2)=(\pi_N^*\omega_1 , \pi_S^*\omega_2)$
with $\omega_i \in H^k(M)$
and we just need to prove that $\omega_1 =\omega_2$.
But we have by hypothesis $\mbox{pr}^* \omega_1 = \mbox{pr}^* \omega_2$
thus we only need to prove that $\mbox{pr}^*$ is injective.

To do this I see that $\mbox{pr}\circ u_A$ is still a retraction thus giving us 
another isomorphism $(\mbox{pr}\circ u_A)^* = u_A^* \circ \mbox{pr}^*$
thus proving that $\mbox{pr}^*$ is injective.

The rest I use the rank theorem in the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence, to get
$$\dim H^k(\mathbb{S}^1\times M)=\dim H^k(M) + \dim H^{k-1}(M)$$.

If there is a kind soul to comment on it I would be grateful

Comment: In the list of related questions to this one, I see a complete duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472949/ It was not answered, but there are some hints in the comments!

Künneth formula is not that difficult, but I think that the whole point of your exercise is to avoid it and instead understand the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence for de Rham cohomology.

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that question when searching the forum. I applied the hints given in the post. I think the kernel is $\simeq H^k(M)$, but I can't manage to prove it.